# HttpWebRequest in .NET Core 2.0 throwing 302 Found Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, system.net.httpwebrequest, asp.net-core-2.0

We are upgrading our application from .net framework to .net core 2.0.

In it, we use a `HttpWebRequest` to contact a site with `AllowAutoRedirect` set to false. When the code executed `request.GetResponse()` The site will return a 302 response, which in .net framework is OK - you can take response and handle it (we are after the `set-cookie` header value).

However, in .net core 2.0, a WebException gets thrown:

```
The remote server returned an error: (302) Found.
```

Is my understanding incorrect in that a 302 should result in an exception being thrown, rather if AllowAutoRedirect is set to false then the response should still be returned? Is there any way to trigger the same behavior experienced in .net framework?

Comment: For others who arrive here too, I'm experience some differences in the cookie behaviour from .NET Framework to .NET Core, the "HttpOnly" flag appears to be set differently too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the same error when setting `AllowAutoRedirect` to `false`.
I solved the problem by just wrapping a `try-catch`-block around `request.GetResponse()` and assigning the Result of the exception to a variable

```
WebResponse response;
try {
   response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch(WebException e)) {
   if(e.Message.Contains("302")
      response = e.Result;
}
```

Comment: It is supposed to be e..Response

Comment: I'd suggest a slight modification to the catch block; catch (WebException ex) { response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response; if(response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Redirect) throw (ex); }  makes things a little more concise rather than relying on a consistent string message.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this issue - [HttpWebRequest in .NET Core 2.0 throwing 301 Moved Permanently](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23422). In short, it says:

> If you set `AllowAutoRedirect`, then you will end up not following the
>   redirect. That means ending up with the 301 response.
>
> `HttpWebRequest` (unlike `HttpClient`) throws exceptions for
>   non-successful (non-200) status codes. So, getting an exception (most
>   likely a `WebException`) is expected.
>
> So, if you need to handle that redirect (which is HTTPS -> HTTP by the
>   way), you need to trap it in try/catch block and inspect the
>   `WebException` etc. That is standard use of `HttpWebRequest`.
>
> That is why we recommend devs use `HttpClient` which has an easier use
>   pattern.